# How to shift focus from a page A to page B in HTML4?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, html4

I have a old ASP Classic application that shows a dashboard in a 42 TV for the people working on the Call Center. The dashboard is just a web page with a big SQL script behind. There is too much data in the dashboard and the phone executives that sit so far away from the TV, they get very hard to see the information. So I want to cut the dashboard in 2 webpages, so when then principal dashboard web pages loads (it loads every 15 minutes), after 1 minute it loads the second page, and after 1 more minute it load the first page, and so on until pass 15 minutes and the dashboard load data from the database again.

How can I program this in HTML4 and classic ASP? any ideas?

P.D.: The SQL script is slow, that why it loads every 15 minutes, when I pass from page A to page B, the data must be static, I dont want to call the SQL script again.

Comment: Place information in two separate divs, use `setInterval` function in the browser to hide A - show B / hide B - show A